# Android: How can i set a timeout for SSL sockets for a blocking read/write using the ThreadSafeClientConnectionMana­ger?

Tags: java, android

How can i set a timeout for SSL sockets for a blocking read/write using the ThreadSafeClientConnectionMana­get? I've found that losing network connectivity while reading or writing a SSL socket results in a 15 minute timeout on Android OS 2.2 and 2.3 devices.

I set the following timeouts on my HttpClient:

```
    mParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(mParams, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(mParams, "UTF-8");
    HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(mParams, USER_AGENT);

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(mParams, TIME_OUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(mParams, TIME_OUT);

    ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(mParams, TIME_OUT);

    final SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme(HTTP_SCHEME, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme(HTTPS_SCHEME, SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));

    final ThreadSafeClientConnManager manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(mParams, registry);

    mClient = new DefaultHttpClient(manager, mParams);
```

I then use the client to perform a http put request with a file entity. If I turn on airplane mode in mid upload, wait 15-30 seconds and then turn off airplane mode the socket will be stuck in either a read or write and won't timeout for 15 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Not to pivot away from your very legitimate question, but the blog post [Android's HTTP Clients](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) recommends using [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for new development.  Have you considered switching APIs?

Comment: Since we need to support Froyo and there are problems with HttpURLConnection on that release we won't be switching APIs. In addition we have a good amount of custom code around the Apache client that has no equivalent in HttpURLConnection until ICS. Thanks for suggestion anyway though.